# Get HTML contents of child elems

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Basically I want to transform:

```
<tabs>
<section tab-pane>
    <header tab-header>Tab title with HTML <img ...></header>
    Section body
</section>
<section tab-pane>
    ....
</section>
</tabs>
```

to (Twitter's bootstrap):

```
<div class="tabbable">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li ng-repeat="pane in panes" ng-class="{active:pane.selected}">
          <a href="" ng-click="select(pane)" >TITLE GOES HERE</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content" ng-transclude>
          TABS HERE
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Directives allow you to specify classes, could you just create the structure you want for twitter bootstrap and then have your directives restrict on 'C' instead of 'EA'

Comment: Have you seen [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap)? We have a set of ever-improving pure AngularJS directives based on Twitter Bootstrap, including the tabs.